# Checking function parameters on expressions

Tags: ecmascript-6

The specification has the following line

> Let hasParameterExpressions be ContainsExpression of formals.

This line refers to the following:

> **14.1.5 Static Semantics: ContainsExpression**
>
> *FormalParameters:[empty]*
>
> 1. Return false.
>
> *FormalParameters:FormalParameterList,FunctionRestParameter*
>
> 1. If ContainsExpression of FormalParameterList is true, return true.
> 2. Return ContainsExpression of FunctionRestParameter.
>
> *FormalParameterList:FormalParameterList,FormalParameter*
>
> 1. If ContainsExpression of FormalParameterList is true, return true.
> 2. Return ContainsExpression of FormalParameter.

I don’t quite understand how all the above instructions should apply. For example, we have 3 parameters (a, b = 5, c). The final step in calculating FormalParameter will be

> *SingleNameBinding:BindingIdentifier*
>
> 1. Return false.
>
> *SingleNameBinding:BindingIdentifierInitializer*
>
> 1. Return true.

But I do not understand how I should read this:

> *FormalParameterList:FormalParameterList,FormalParameter*
>
> 1. If ContainsExpression of FormalParameterList is true, return true.
> 2. Return ContainsExpression of FormalParameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an input of `a, b = 5, c`, the grammar would break down as

```
1. FormalParameters(a, b = 5, c)
      |
2. FormalParameterList(a, b=5, c)
      |------------------------------------------------
      |                                               |
3. FormalParameterList(a, b=5)                    , FormalParameter(c)
      |-------------------------                      |
      |                        |                      |
4. (FormalParameterList(a), FormalParameter(b=5)) , FormalParameter(c)
      |                        |                      |
5. ((FormalParameter(a))  , FormalParameter(b=5)) , FormalParameter(c)
```

The grammar is defined here as a recursive structure. You could keep drilling down and expanding `FormalParameter` to get to `Identifer` and so on, but hopefully this is enough of an example.

So to calculate `ContainsExpression`, you can see that the first rule, as you recurse down this tree that matches is

> FormalParameterList: FormalParameterList , FormalParameter
>
> 1. If ContainsExpression of FormalParameterList is true, return true.
> 2. Return ContainsExpression of FormalParameter.

because you can see that on 2&3 that it is a `FormalParameterList` made up of another `FormalParameterList`, a comma, and then a `FormalParameter`.

If you think of this like an tree, you can imagine this function as

```
function ContainsExpression(node) {
  if (node.type === "FormalParameterList") {
    // Step 1
    if (ContainsExpression(node.left)) return true;
    // Step 2
    return ContainsExpression(node.right);
  }
  // ...
}
```

so that will recurse down the left and right side of each `FormalParameterList`. It is essentially a depth-first search through the tree, terminating as soon as something returns `true`.

That means that eventually `ContainsExpression` will recurse down until the `node` argument is `FormalParameter`. We then get to [`ContainsExpression` for Bindings](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns-static-semantics-containsexpression) because `FormalParameter` is defined as `BindingElement`, which has

> ```
> BindingElement: SingleNameBinding Initializer
>
>     Return true.
> ```

so eventually the recursion above will call `ContainsExpression` for `FormalParameter(b=5))`, and since `b = 5` matches `SingleNameBinding Initializer`, `ContainsExpression` will return `true`. Then the depth-first search is done.

Comment: AST tree is clear, I imagined it. `BindingElement: BindingPattern Initializer` - still different from `SingleNameBinding: BindingIdentifier Initializer`. You are definitely not mistaken? You also gave an example with `function ContainsExpression`. What will be the result of `return ContainsExpression (node.right);`. For some reason I imagine `false` In general, I still did not understand how to parse the parameters with the function that you wrote

Comment: You're right, it should be `SingleNameBinding`, my mistake. "For some reason I imagine false In general," It would entirely depend on the code. It will either be `true` or `false` depending on the code. For `a, b, c=5` for instance, it would recurse through the tree and eventually return `true` from the right side.

Comment: The most important thing that I do not understand is that algorithm. I do not see in it cyclicality. The first step for me looks like a list of parameters, but we can not return either true or false since it is not parsed into elements. The second step is to return false in `SingleNameBinding: BindingIdentifier` or return true in `SingleNameBinding: BindingIdentifier Initializer`. So where is the recursion here, I don’t understand?

Comment: Here is the ast tree that you described there pure recursion following the parsing grammar `FormalParameterList: FormalParameter` or `FormalParameterList: FormalParameterList, FormalParameter`. In general, we need an example of how you parse the arguments that I provided in the question, not in the ast tree, as you already did, but for `ContainsExpression`

Comment: `So where is the recursion here` As 14.1.5 in your question shows, the function is declared to call itself. That is recursion. I don't know what part of that is unclear. "we can not return either true or false since it is not parsed into elements." I don't know what you mean here. The rules of the function are declared per-grammar-node, so by definition you have a grammar node and thus have parsed the code.

Comment: "In general, we need an example of how you parse the arguments that I provided in the question, not in the ast tree, as you already did, but for ContainsExpression" My example is not an AST, is a grammar tree. The tree is based on the grammar in the spec and does not vary by function. The `ContainsExpression` function is defined in piece-wise fashion for each grammar element and calls itself on the various child grammar nodes that it has, until it returns `true`.

Comment: Where is that piece of code that calls itself? "we can not return either true or false since it is not parsed into elements." - by this I meant the integrity of the structure which cannot be calculated without taking it into pieces in this case on FormalParameter[s]. Ooops is definitely not an AST. "The tree is based on the grammar in the spec and does not vary by function" - this is understandable.

Comment: The `ContainsExspression` function we are talking about is supplied with the parameters `(a, b = 5, c)`. As you said, this can be regarded as a node, and I will act as a node containing subnodes. Accordingly, the first step that the second in this function can be recursive, it all depends on what parameters are set. In our case, only the first step is recursive, it makes our list break into pieces and move deeper into the recursion.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the analysis by the grammar tree function goes from right to left (did I determine the parsing direction correctly?) And we won’t analyze the parameter “a” since it is on the left, and the analysis will end on the parameter “b = 5”. Did I understand everything correctly?

Comment: Well then, how should I represent one parameter? It is in fact a list of parameters, but it cannot be broken down into the following construct: `FormalParameterList: FormalParameterList, FormalParameter`